# How should i use community chef cookbooks?

Tags: chef-infra, provisioning, chef-recipe

Should i just download finished community cookbooks from supermarket, or there is some special mechanism (or package manager) for them, and i can just import them in my recipes somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like berkshelf to manage dependencies.

So if you have a community cookbook like "rvm" and you want to use a portion of the cookbook you might create your own cookbook called "my_rvm"

Then in "my_rvm" you would modify your "metadata.rb" file and add a dependency for "rvm":

```
depends "rvm"
```

then in the default recipe for "my_rvm" you might put a documented rvm recipe:

```
include_recipe "rvm::system"
```

Then in the root of your "my_rvm" cookbook you would type:

```
berks install
```

This will install the dependency cookbook on your workstation so that it is available to your new customized "my_rvm" cookbook.